# How convert GPS Latitude/longitude/altitude to Cartesian coordinates?

Tags: python, gps, cartesian, imu

I get my robot's location from an IMU's GPS sensor. It outputs the robot's location in latitude, longitude, and altitude format. Latitude and longitude are in degrees and altitude is in meters and it is elevation from sea level.

I want to convert it to the cartesian coordinate system, what is the correct way for it? Is there any Python package for it?

Comment: Yes, there is a package for that. But it depends on the use (distance your robot will travel, and if it will go near the poles. Probably you need precision and fast calculations, so do it manually (set up x,y,z = 0,0,0 at first fix after reboot), and check how much a degree of latitude and longitute is in meters (at first fix), so you have just a proportion to do. Look "degree of latitude" and "..of lingitude" in wikipedia. Very easy